# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api, use-state

I have seen similar questions to this on stack overflow and various other sites, but none of them resolved this issue. I am trying to make a custom fetch hook in TS as follows

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export type FetchResponse = {
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  data: any;
  error: any;
  loading: boolean;
};

export const useCustomFetch = (
  url: string,
  params: Record<string, string>,
  customBase?: string
): FetchResponse => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<number>(0);
  const [statusText, setStatusText] = useState<string>('');
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        url + '?' + new URLSearchParams(params)
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      setStatus(response.status);
      setStatusText(response.statusText);
      setData(json);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return { data, loading, error, status, statusText };
};
```

However, this code errors out upon running with the following message [image]

I think this has something to do with useState() not being defined correctly. I vaguely remembering encountering this before. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you can use react states outside an component?

Comment: Make sure you instantiate your hook useCustomFetch inside another hook or component

Comment: Thank you for these replies. I had to instantiate the hook first. I was directly calling upon it.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I had the same error and it was because I was using "/api/" in a route in NEXTJS

my pages structure:

-pages
--admin
--api